# JavaFX, full screen: app blinks when alert is shown

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have a very simple application in JavaFX: full screen stage with one exit button. Problem is that from time to time (no idea why not always) after clicking on "Exit" button my application blinks (seems that is minimized and maximized in miliseconds).
Any ideas?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCombination;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;    
import java.util.Optional;

public class FullScreenExample extends Application {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Button button = new Button("Exit");
        button.setOnAction(event -> {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
            alert.initOwner(stage);
            alert.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
            alert.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
            Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
            if (result.get() == ButtonType.OK){
                Platform.exit();
            }
        });
        VBox box = new VBox();
        box.getChildren().add(button);
        final Scene scene = new Scene(box);
        scene.setFill(null);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setFullScreenExitHint("");
        stage.setFullScreenExitKeyCombination(KeyCombination.NO_MATCH);
        stage.setFullScreen(true);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wich java version you are using (Update?)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Stage style Undecorated:

```
  alert.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
```

Try to use

```
alert.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
```

This fixes your blinking.

Its a known Issue with the Undecorated Frame in Windows.

Comment: Nope, still from time to time its blinking. Maybe it is because of windows version? I have win7.

Comment: Then try the default StageStyle. If this dont help I dont have any more idears.

Comment: Can you test your app on another PC? Maybe its an Problem on your PC only.

Comment: I was playing with different stageStyles and always same problem. Yes, I will have to try on different pc. thanks